# Appcelerator: JSON.parse not doing anything within socket

Tags: javascript, json, socket.io, titanium, bonjour

Im using the code from the following tutorial:

http://cssgallery.info/advanced-titanium-tutorial-bonjour-networking/

but as this is 2 years old it doesn't seem to work 100% (guessing because of some api changes)

as far as i can tell its not working because it breaks when trying to parse a string as json

this bit:

```
var connection = bjnet(win.player.name, function(data){
    var json_data = JSON.parse(data);
    make_blob(json_data.player,json_data.coords);//this is just a function that makes the ...blobs!
});
```

for some reason it is having trouble parsing the following string as json:

```
data = {"coords":{"x":166,"y":443},"player":{"color":"#0f0","name":"green"}}
```

and i cant figure out why! ive confirmed its a string etc, but after trying all day to fix it myself ive now admitted defeat and hoping a genius out there can help me!

btw the above function is called in the "read" event listener for "Titanium.Network.TCPSocket"

Thanks for your time :)

Comment: if i use JSON.stringify on the data var (which is a string I just forgot the quotes) i get this: 

"{\"coords\":{\"x\":185.5,\"y\":300},\"player\":{\"color\":\"#0f0\",\"name\":\"green\"}}\u0000"

Comment: what actually happens when you try to parse it? do you get an error?

Comment: @David:If you already have data in JSON string format(from your above disussion), then i don't think it troubles you in parsing data with JSON.parse(data). But since, you are facing a problem, there is an alternative for this which do the same thing, try eval('(' + data + ')'), it work same as JSON.parse, but it might not be preferable choice, since it have some loopholes.

Comment: @ben336: yes, i get "unable to parse JSON string", if i use JSON.parse on the same string anywhere other than in the functions below it parses fine.

    service.socket.addEventListener('read', function(x) {
        fn_receive(x['data'].text); // this is calling the function below
    }); 

    var connection = bjnet(win.player.name, function(data){
 
    });

is it anything to do with the fact im trying to parse it in a socket event listener? but then why would that mater?

"@Mohit Pandey": i tried eval('(' + data + ')') but pretty much got same error "parse error"

Thanks for the help so far

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ive fixed it! .. well not me but someone else on this thread: http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/126520/tcp-sockets-and-jsonparse

turns out the socket was adding an extra character to the data being sent that was not playing nice with the json parser

it works fine now

thanks for your help guys :)